# Docker 17 fails to start in Centos 7

Tags: docker, daemon, systemd, docker-machine, systemctl

We have installed docker 17.12 in our Centos 7.x and after the installation is complete, am facing an error while trying to start the docker service. Initially, I tried for `systemctl` docker start then for more output on this when I tried `journalctl` it says `docker.service` entered failed state.

More details below:

```
Docker :
17.12.1-ce , build 7390fc6

Command tried:
sudo systemctl start docker
journalctl -u docker.service

Expected Output:
Docker service should be started successfully

Actual output:
Mar 26 23:51:19  docker[16420]: See 'docker --help'
Mar 26 23:51:19  systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 26 23:51:19  systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 26 23:51:19  systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 26 23:51:19  docker.service failed.
Mar 26 23:51:21  systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 26 23:51:21 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Mar 26 23:51:21  systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 26 23:51:21  systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 26 23:51:21  systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Mar 26 23:52:22  systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Mar 26 23:52:22  docker[16582]: docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command.
Mar 26 23:52:22  docker[16582]: See 'docker --help'
Mar 26 23:52:22  systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 26 23:52:22  systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 26 23:52:22  systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 26 23:52:22  systemd[1]: docker.service failed.                                                                                  
Mar 26 23:52:24  systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 26 23:52:24  systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Mar 26 23:52:25  docker[16601]: docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command.
Mar 26 23:52:25  docker[16601]: See 'docker --help'
Mar 26 23:52:25  systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 26 23:52:25  systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 26 23:52:25  systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 26 23:52:25  systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Mar 26 23:52:27  systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 26 23:52:27  systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Mar 26 23:52:27  docker[16619]: docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command.
Mar 26 23:52:27  docker[16619]: See 'docker --help'
Mar 26 23:52:27  systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 26 23:52:27  systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 26 23:52:27  systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 26 23:52:27  systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Mar 26 23:52:29  systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 26 23:52:29  systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Mar 26 23:52:29  systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 26 23:52:29  systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 26 23:52:29  systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Please check on this issue and help us resolve the docker start issue.

Answer (score 0):

no evidence in your log.

Would you just reinstall with the official way ?

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
$ sh get-docker.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's another issue with:

`sudo dockerd --debug`

In my situation I had invalid config in the daemon.json.